# How would one replicate this scrolling effect?

Tags: css, effects

https://medium.com/message/81e5f33a24e1

When you scroll down past individual sections, the background fades out as you scroll past a certain marker and the header text fades in. I assumed this was some sort of CSS transition, but I found it difficult to navigate the css on that particular site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A javascript is watching the scroll:

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    var scroll = window.pageYOffset;
    //do smth (like if you've reached the div, add a class to it)
}
```

and when reaching the div to transform, you add a class to it (or you remove it upon scrolling upward). The transformations brought by this class (`.reachedByScroll` in my example) are then defined in css:

```
div.reachedByScroll .background{
    filter: blur(10px);
}
div.reachedByScroll .text{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

for smoothness, you can also add a `transition` in the css.

This answer details how things appear with scroll but not how the scrolling is slowed down. That is not what was asked.